# Algorithm to find the maxima of a given set of items

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime, max

---

I have written a program in python that displays the set of maximum values that are entered into database. When an item is incomparable to the maxima, it is added to the maxima

Currently I am performing a linear search through the entire database. The problem is the worst case runtime is O(n^2). I was wndering is there can be a better implementation for this algorithm.

```
    maxima = []
    for item in items:
        should_insert = 1;
        for val in maxima:
            comp = self.test(item, val)
            if comp == 1:
                should_insert = 0
                break
            elif comp == -1:
                maxima.remove(val)
        if should_insert == 1:
            maxima.append(item)
    return maxima
```

Comment: You can not remove an element from a collection while you are iterating it.

Comment: What is the "set of maximum values"? Is there more than one? Can you give an example?

Comment: So, your `maxima` are actually (1) one element that's the actual maximum, and (2) a number of elements (all, in the worst case) that are not comparable to the maximum? Could you explain on this "not comparable" idea?

Comment: What if an element was added to maxima because it was not comparable to the (at that time) maximum element, but then you found a greater element, to which is _is_ comparable? I'd suggest you do two passes: First, find the one maximum element, second find all the elements that are "imcomparable" to that one absolute maximum.

Comment: I think the question is unclear, also you have a wrong tag. Read a maxima tag decsription  NOTE: This tag has NOTHING to do with 'finding the maxima' - for that, please use [max].

Comment: I don't think there's any way around the `O(N^2)` worst case behavior. That will always happen if all the values are incomparable to each other, so you're just going to have to deal with it unless there's some other way to group comparable values without doing the comparison itself (e.g. different types or something).

Comment: @interjay I actually use this code in recommendation systems(for example aparment listings) where two items may be incomparable due to the user request (ex: The use wants an apartment with 2 bedrooms and 2 bathrooms and we the query returns rooms with 3 bedrooms and 3 bathrooms with equal importance to 1 bedroom and 1 bathroom appartments)

Comment: @Blckknght Ya but I was thinking if I used something like merge sort, the runtime can be improved?

Comment: @tobias_k I actually use this code in recommendation systems(for example aparment listings) where two items may be incomparable due to the user request (ex: The user wants an apartment with 2 bedrooms and 2 bathrooms and the query returns rooms with 3 bedrooms and 3 bathrooms with equal importance to 1 bedroom and 1 bathroom apartments. This is n example of incomparable items)

Comment: The way it is now, the result is non-deterministic. Say you have elements A and B, with A > B, and a1, ..., an, all smaller than A and incomparable to B, and b1, ..., bn, smaller than B and incomparable to A. If those elements are ordered [B,a1,...,an,A,b1,...bn], then _all of those_ except B will be "maxima", while if they are ordered [A,b1,...bn,B,a1,...,an], then only [A,b1,...bn] will be maxima. I really think your logic with "incomparable" elements does not work out that way...

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no way to improve on this.

However there are usually many linear extensions of your partial order that turn your partial order into a total order.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension for what I mean by that.)  Let's suppose that you can find several which, between them, have the property that two elements are comparable in the original order if and only if they compare the same way on each.  Now what you can do is take your set, do a heapsort using the first ordering until you find the first element not comparable with your max.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort for that algorithm, which in Python is available from https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html.)  Take that set, switch to the second ordering, and repeat.  Continue until you've used all orderings.

If you have `n` elements, and `k` such orderings, then this algorithm's worst case running time is `O(k * n * log(n))`.  And frequently it will be much better - if `m` is the size of the group that you pull out on the first step, the running time is `O(n + k * m * log(n))`.

Your ability to use this approach will, unfortunately, depend on whether you can find several total extensions of your partial ordering that have this property.  But in many cases you can.  For instance for one ordering you break your original sort on number of bathrooms ascending, and in the next on number of bathrooms descending.  And so on.

Comment: could you elaborate on how this would work? For example I desire all bedrooms with 2 bathrooms and 2 bedrooms. Now I obtain two partial orders one on bathrooms(2 being max here, 1 and 3 being equal and so on) and one on bedrooms. How would i combine these two ?

Comment: @KarthikReddy Order one would be on quality of match, breaking ties by number of bathrooms, breaking ties by number of bedrooms, breaking ties by apartment ID.  Order two would be on quality of match and then all the same criteria, in the same order, but with ties broken the opposite way.  A heap by the first order can pull off everything of maximum quality.  Switch to the second order, and you can make sure that they are all incomparable with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear what you mean by "incomparable" values. If you mean *equal* values, then you probably want a simple variation on the normal `max` function, allowing it to return multiple equal values:

```
def find_maxima_if_incomparable_means_equal(self, items):
    it = iter(items)
    maxima = [next(it)] # TODO: change the exception type raised here if items is empty

    for item in it:
        comp = self.test(item, maxima[0])
        if comp == 0:
            maxima.append(item)
        elif comp < 0:
            maxima = [item]

    return maxima
```

On the other hand, if you really mean it when you say that some cannot be compared (i.e. that comparing them has no meaning), the situation is more complicated. You want to find a "maxima" subset of the values such that each item in the maxima set is either greater than or incomparable to every other item in the original set. If your set was `[1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c"]`, you'd expect the maxima to be `[3, "c"]`, since integers and strings cannot be compared to each other (at least, not in Python 3).

There's no way to avoid the potential of `O(N^2)` running time in the general case. That's because if none of your items can be compared to any of the others, the maxima set is going to end up being the same as the whole set, and you'll have to have tested every item against every other item to be sure they're really incomparable.

In fact, in the most general case where there's no requirement of a total ordering among any of the values (e.g. `a < b < c` does not imply `a < c`), you probably have to compare every item to every other item always. Here's a function that does exactly that:

```
import itertools

def find_maxima_no_total_ordering(self, items):
    non_maximal = set()

    for a, b in itertools.combinations(items, 2):
        comp = self.test(a, b)
        if comp > 0:
            non_maximal.add(a)
        elif comp < 0:
            non_maximal.add(b)

    return [x for x in items if x not in non_maximal]
```

Note that the maxima returned by this function may be empty, if the comparisons are bizarre enough that there are cycles (e.g. `A < B`, `B < C` and `C < A` are all true).

If your specific situation is more limited, you may have some better options. If your set of items is the union of of several totally ordered groups (such that `A < B < C` implies `A < C` and that `A incomparable-to B and B < C` implies `A incomparable-to C`), and there's no easy way to separate out the incomparable groups, you can use an algorithm similar to what your current code attempts, which will be `O(M*N)` where `N` is the number of items and `M` is the number of totally ordered groups. This is still `O(N^2)` in the worst case (`N` groups) but somewhat better if the items end up belonging to just a few groups. If all items are comparable to each other, it's `O(N)` (and the maxima will contain just a single value). Here's an improved version of your code:

```
def find_maxima_with_total_orderings(self, items):
    maxima = set() # use a set for fast removal

    for item in items:
        for val in maxima:
            comp = self.test(item, val)
            if comp == 1:
                break
            elif comp == -1:
                maxima.remove(val)
                maxima.add(item)
                break
        else:     # else clause is run if there was no break in the loop
            maxima.add(item)

    return maxima # you may want to turn this into a list again before returning it
```

You can do even better if the group an item belongs to can be determined easily (for instance, by checking the item's type). You can first subdivide the items into their groups, then find the maximum of each totally ordered group. Here's code that's `O(N)` for all cases, assuming that there's an `O(1)` running time method `self.group` that returns some hashable value so that if `self.group(A) == self.group(B)` then `self.test(A, B) != 0`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def _max(comparable_items): # a helper function, find max using self.test rather than >
    it = iter(comparable_items)
    max_item = next(it)

    for item in it:
        if self.test(item, max_item) < 0:
            max_item = item

    return max_item

def find_maxima_with_groups(self, items):
    groups = defaultdict(list)

    for item in items:
        groups[self.group(item)].append(item)

    return [self._max(g) for g in groups.values()]
```